# How do I read multiple lines from a file?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function that takes an input file from the command line. The input file looks like this:

```
11 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3
1 3 5
1 2 2
```

I want to store the two numbers on the first line in integer variables. The second line is stored in an array. And the third and following lines are stored in another container. Currently I have a program that can read from the first line:

```
void classFunctions::storeInput(const char* inputFile)
{
  std::ifstream file(inputFile);
  std::string placeholderString;
  while(!file.eof())
  {
    while(std::getline(file, placeholderString))
    {
     //Do something
    }
  }
}
```

But how would I change this so it can read from the second, third, and following lines?

Comment: You should clarify your question, do you mean that you want to store each number on each line as a separate element in some container, or do you mean that you just want to store the whole line in a container?

I.e, should it be read line and then then go over all the space separated elements in the line and treat each space separated thing as it's own element?

Because if you just want to read the whole file until eof, your code already does that just fine, if you wanted to store each line in a vector or something, it would be a trivial change.

Answer (score 0):

After checking if the text file is empty or not, you should call `getline()` twice and keep reading until `eof()`

```
getline(file, first_line);
//proceed to process with a stringstream
getline(file, second_line);
//process
while(true) {
    string line;
    getline(file, line);
    //process
    if(file.eof()) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line is simply an extraction into two variables. For the second line, `std::getline()` should be used, and you should probably but it in a `std::istringstream` and use `std::istream_iterator` to parse the line into the array. The rest of the lines require successive calls to `std::getline()` as well.